# Is there any way I can keep track of every object in a python application (e.g., using unique ids)?

Tags: python, instrumentation

I am trying to create a model that represents parts of an execution of a python application (Logging the creation of some objects, accessing attributes, looping over, etc.).

An issue I haven't been able to resolve is that I could not find a way to identify an object every time I encounter it.

Is there any way I can track every object during an application execution (to know that an object is the same one encountered earlier or another one)?

- I am doing this as I want to have some logs (or traces) of the application runtime to be able to infer some patterns from the logs later on. This is intended to be a library that could be installed into another project, instrument its code and gather the necessary logs.
- Right now I am using [DynaPyt](https://github.com/sola-st/DynaPyt) to instrument the code. (Meaning that I **have** access to the objects that I am logging, but may not be able to change their source code)

I tried using `id(x)` but this is not right due to the `id` function not having a meaningful return value, and even having duplicate values for different objects if their lifetimes do not overlap (in CPython at least, I believe, as it returns the object's memory address).

I also tried attaching a `UUID` to the objects throughout the code, to use that for tracking them, however not all objects permit adding attributes to them.
I tried converting builtin instances to some custom classes which inherit from them, to be able to attach a `UUID` to them. Something like:

```
class CustomList(list):
    pass
```

But then again, I believe that this may have performance problems, and also there are (unlimited, I assume) other immutable objects such as the `UUID` object itself, that don't let me attach attributes to them.

Comment: Add code to the `__init__()` methods that adds `(self, id(self))` in global list.

Comment: @Barmar I am writing a code that is instrumenting and running another (third-party) code. I am trying to write a library, or a tool (not sure which definition it fits in). Meaning that I am trying to track objects in different applications, either user-defined, built-in, or imported from libraries. I don't necessarily have access to all of their implementations. Also, I think your suggestion would mess with garbage collection and will stop it from collecting those objects, which causes performance issues.

Comment: I don't think there's an easy way for you to track objects of third-party libraries, although you might be able to do it with monkey-patching. Regarding GC, use `weakref`, although then you won't have unique `id()`, so you won't actually be able to "track" things.

Comment: Yes, the problem with garbage collection is that if I block it, it will cause performance problems, and if I don't, then `id()` won't be unique. I tried monkey-patching (as stated in the question) by attaching attributes in runtime, but then there is the problem of immutable objects. The only other way I can think of is to have a custom subclass of everything (dynamically) and then change every object to use that, but I don't think it is feasible as there are some classes which I cannot subclass from, and also it is very hard, I presume, to preserve every behaviour exactly as-is.

Comment: HI @NimaMG a possible woarkaround for immutable objects such as `tuple` variants would be to subclass them and add the id funtionality in the `__new__` method intead of `__init__`, before you pass the arguments to its parent's `constructor`.

Comment: The problem is that there are various classes that are immutable. If there were only a few (such as tuples) I could work around it somehow, but there may be various other immutable objects (custom frozen data classes, for example). I don't have a feasible way of subclassing all of those. @HernanATN

Comment: It's not really clear to me what you mean by "track". What are you doing with all these objects that you're tracking? How can you do it if you allow them to be GCed?

Comment: @Barmar I am trying to create a model representing that execution path. Consider `a.b`, I have a graph that has two nodes for `a` and `b` and an edge showing that `b` is the result of attribute access on `a`. (The nodes represent the objects, not the names or variables.)
To do this, I am trying to instrument the code (which injects some hooks into the code, that calls my defined functions), run the code (running my hooks in the process), and log the events that happen in the code. I need to distinguish the objects, and be able to infer if an object is the same as a previous one or not.

Comment: I don't see any way to accomplish this without either using `weakref` or preventing GC. To test if an object is the same as a previous one, you need to save a reference to the previous one somewhere. But I'm really not sure how you'll instrument the code to get references to every object that's created -- many could be created internally by the interpreter.

Answer (score -2):

So I think I understand what you're trying to do and I like the concept is so here is my attempt at making it work.

the concept is to simply hash the name, address and values to create a unique ID then save the address and name to a dict to be compared later and return the unique ID.

```
import traceback


class OUID:

    addressList = {}

    def __init__(self, obj: object) -> str:
        """returns a unique ID for an object"""

        # get object id
        memA = id(obj)

        # Get object name
        name = self.n(obj)

        # get exisitng OUID from dict
        if memA in self.addressList:
            if name in self.addressList[memA]:
                ouid = self.addressList[memA][name]
                self.value = ouid
        else:
            self.addressList.__setitem__(memA, {})

            if isinstance(obj, (list, dict, set, tuple)):
                objHash = self.listhash(obj=obj)
            elif isinstance(obj, float):
                objHash = obj.__hash__()
            else:
                try:
                    objHash = obj.__hash__()
                except TypeError:
                    objHash = obj.__hash__(obj)
    
            finalhash = (memA + objHash + name).__hash__()
    
            self.value = hex(abs(finalhash))
    
            self.addressList[memA][name] = self.value  

    def __str__(self) -> str:
        """returns the id"""
        return self.value

    def listhash(self, obj: object) -> str:
        """Creates a hash for a list object."""

        data = ""

        for i in obj:
            if isinstance(i, (list, dict, set, tuple)):
                pass
            hashitem = str(str(i).__hash__())
            data += str(str(i).__hash__())

        return data.__hash__()
    
    def n(self, obj: object):
        """returns hash of the objects name"""

        if isinstance(obj, (int, float, str, list, dict, set, bool, tuple)):
            return self.varname(obj=obj)
        else:
            return str(obj.__repr__).split(" ")[3].__hash__()
        
    def varname(self, obj: object) -> str:
        """
        Get the variable names of objects.
        """
        stack = traceback.extract_stack()
        stack = stack[-4].line.split("(")

        name = ''.join(stack[-1]).replace(')', '')

        return name.__hash__()
```

So you are right hashing doesn't work when it comes to list and other data types so I came up with a way to id ab object. Not completely sure how you could implement into your project. It definitely needs some work.

here are the test I ran.

```
mylist = [1,2,3,4]
mytuple = ({"cake":"vanilla"},2,3,5)
mydict = {"key":"value"}
num = 1
name = "flock"
double = 1.2

def foo():
    return 0

myfunc = foo()

class Myclass:
    def __init__(self) -> None:
        pass

myclass = Myclass

mycls = Myclass()

ouid = OUID


print("list:\t",ouid(mylist))
print("tuple:\t",ouid(mytuple))
print("dict:\t",ouid(mydict))
print("int:\t",ouid(num))
print("str:\t",ouid(name))
print("float:\t",ouid(double))
print("def\t",ouid(foo))
print("myfunc\t",ouid(myfunc))
print("class1\t",ouid(myclass))
print("class2\t",ouid(mycls))

mylist.pop(2) # if you edit the list it will not change the id

print("list:\t",ouid(mylist))

mydict["shoes\t"] = "kickers"

print("dict:\t",ouid(mydict))

new_ouid = OUID

print("list:\t",new_ouid(mylist))
```

and here are the results.

```
list:    0xaf1307d9124e686
tuple:   0x23a4d66fc8b7844
dict:    0x1813a3de28406330
int:     0x45dbfdfea240465
str:     0x2ea2bb2765bebb9
float:   0xcc876b2375534c8
def:     0xf43d5582e10066a
myfunc:  0x1b3b3a71769330e4
class1:  0x1eb47e49f24bb28
class2:  0x16d317accb27b058
list:    0xaf1307d9124e686
dict:    0x1813a3de28406330
list:    0xaf1307d9124e686
```

Comment: This can't be used as a general approach, as it cannot be assumed that every object is hashable. A list is a very simple example of an object that is not hashable.